# Where has the Ubuntu software centre installed boost to?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, path

I've used the ubuntu software centre to install libboost1.40-dev. But I've not got a clue as to where it's been put. I'm not great with *nix, so I'm not sure where it would go normally, and there seem to be a lot of viable places too.

However, it's not being found by G++, so I don't think it's anywhere in the $PATH.

Comment: Not the answer, but related: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-ubuntu-what-package-did-this-file-come-from/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dpkg-query -L libboost1.40-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a library, not an executable, so it doesn't have to be in $PATH.

Since you mention the -dev package, I assume you are writing code that uses boost. It would help if you would edit your question and would add how are you trying to make use of it.

Also, this looks more like a programming question (for stackoverflow)

Comment: The problem is that I've no idea what ubuntu software centre has done with the boost libraries, and how do I get them to compile. I guess it's two parts, one more valid on SO, but the bigger issue is where the hell are the lib's.

Comment: Libraries are generally in /usr/lib. -dev packages also include headers, which are in /usr/include